# Пытаюсь из 61 минут сделать в 1 час 1 минуту в c#. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: c#, form, время

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы например, стоит 1 час и **61 минуту**, сделал +1 час и остался 1 минута. Если это возможно, то как? Пожалуйста помогите мне.

Вот мой код, который у меня не получился:

Есть вопросы, задавайте мне.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hours = Convert.ToInt32(HourInput.Text);
        minutes = Convert.ToInt32(MinuteInput.Text);

        hoursPlus += hours;
        minutesPlus += minutes;

        if(minutesPlus == 60)
        {
            hoursPlus++;
            minutesPlus = 0;
        }
        else if(minutesPlus >= 61)
        {
            hoursPlus++;
            // тут дальше я запутался...
        }

        TimesRes.Text = "Hours: " + hoursPlus.ToString() + "  |  Minutes: " + minutesPlus.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Для работы с временем и датами в C# уже все есть необходимое (`new TimeSpan(1, 61, 0) //{02:01:00}`). Так что, не изобретайте велосипед, если в этом нету необходимости.

Comment: Достаточно одного условия: `if(minutesPlus > 59) {hoursPlus++; minutesPlus = minutesPlus - 60;}`. Но в целом, это неверное решение, нужно учитывать, что пользователь может ввести любое значение, а значит и часов нужно будет прибавлять более 1. например для 500 минут нужно прибавить 8 часов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока минут 60 или больше увеличиваете часы и вычитаете 60 из минут.

```cs
while(minutesPlus >= 60)
{
    hoursPlus++;
    minutesPlus -= 60;
}
```

Это вместо всего вашего `if ... else ...`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)

Comment: Он же так и сдаст решение?!!! жестоко =)

Answer (score 4):

```
hoursPlus += minutesPlus / 60;
minutesPlus = minutesPlus % 60;
```

Comment: С козырей зашёл ))

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть TimeSpan

```
int hours = 10; 
int minutes = 61; 
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours).Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));

Console.WriteLine($"Hours {timeSpan.Hours}"); // от 0 до 23
Console.WriteLine($"Minutes {timeSpan.Minutes}"); // от 0 до 59
```

Вывод

```
Hours 11
Minutes 1
```

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже хорошо подходит для моего проекта. :)